# Install mitmproxy on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

Tags: macos

i downloaded mitmproxy from: https://github.com/cortesi/mitmproxy and install mitmproxy with the following command:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

If i try to start mitmproxy with:

```
./mitmproxy -p 8899
```

I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mitmproxy", line 19, in <module>
    from libmproxy import proxy, console, cmdline
  File "/Users/carl.jahn/Downloads/cortesi-mitmproxy-bc3ba4c/libmproxy/proxy.py", line 24, in <module>
    import utils, flow, certutils
  File "/Users/carl.jahn/Downloads/cortesi-mitmproxy-bc3ba4c/libmproxy/certutils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyasn1.type import univ, constraint, char, namedtype, tag
ImportError: No module named pyasn1.type
```

How can i fix the errors?

Thanks

**Update:**

ok, i fixed it by

- installing the [current release](http://mitmproxy.org/download/mitmproxy-0.7.tar.gz)
- installing urwid by download from the [current release](http://excess.org/urwid/urwid-1.0.1.tar.gz) and copy the urwid folder (which is within the downloaded urwid-X.X.X folder) in the mitmproxy folder
- installing pyasn1 and pyopenssl with:

  `pip install pyasn1` or (sudo) `easy_install pyasn1`

  `pip install pyopenssl` or (sudo) `easy_install pyopenssl`
- Start the mitmproxy installation with: `sudo python setup.py install`
- And finally start mitmproxy with: `mitmproxy -p 8888`

Comment: You can also just pip install every missing module it complains about (including urwid, lxml..)

Comment: Instead of including the answer in your question, consider moving everything in the "Update" portion to an answer and marking it as correct so future site visitors can find and benefit from it.